# How to save single object into state, from json end point axios

Tags: reactjs

UPDATE:

```
axios
  .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", config)
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({profile: response.data})
  })
```

^ saved the object in state for me :) Thanks everyone!!

I am a newbie to react. I am trying to save a single object from a JSON end point into the state of my react component. I am definitely returning the JSON data in the response. However it is not being saved into the state, can you see where I am going wrong?

```
  // State needed for the component
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profile: {},
    };
  } 

 // Grabs profile data from the json url
  private getProfile() {
    let config = {
      headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer AQVVEqNXTWV....'}
    }
    axios
      .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", config)
      .then(response => 
          response.data(profile => ({
            id: `${ profile.id }`
         }))
        )
        .then(profile => {
          this.setState({
            profile
          });
        })
      // We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

JOSN data returned:

```
{
    "localizedLastName": "King",
    "id": "fm0B3D6y3I",
    "localizedFirstName": "Benn"
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? I can try to help, but I need more details.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first then block? I think it is unnecessary. Can you remove the first then block and try?

Answer (score 1):

Your first then block looks wrong.

Try to do console.log there like this:

```
.then(response => {
  console.log(response); // I am sure that you will get profile inside response.data or something similar
  return response.data(profile => ({
    id: `${ profile.id }`
  }));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the second then, like this:

```
  axios
   .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", config)
    .then(response => {this.setState({ profile: response.data })};
    })
   }))
```

Comment: Ahh this looks like what I got to do! I get an error though `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.data is not a function`

Comment: That is because response.data it's the json file not a function, I've modified the code, if response.data is the JOSN data returned, probably now should work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your first then that "prepares the data", then you should return a promise instead of data, like:

```js
let config = {
  headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer AQVVEqNXTWV....'}
}
axios
  .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", config)
  .then(response =>  {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve( {
          id: `${ response.data.id }`
        });  
      });
    }
  )
  .then(profile => {
    this.setState({
      profile
    });
  })
// We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
.catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
```

Here's an example of how that would work:

[image: Edit strange-curran-b27ni]

I do believe that's a bit of an overkill though and you should be able to just set your state in the first `then` such as:

```
this.setState({profile: {id : response.data.id}});
```